# onloadTime is twice as long as my loadTime

Tags: javascript, firebug, onload, page-load-time

I want to understand what onloadTime means and why it is twice as longer as my total loadTime.

On firebug->networks i get this values: `351ms (onload: 674ms)`

What can be the reason for this discrepancy? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is how long from first request start until last request completion.
The second number is the time until the "load" event fires on the page.
Your load event is firing later due to script processing and DOM creation time in the browser.  This is comparitively good news for your network latency but comparitively bad news for your browser/computer speed.
See this article for more: 
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-net-panel-timings/